# How to use if else statement

Tags: c++, console-application

Today I want to test if a user types the word "yes" in console application, then the function will proceed, however, I am unable to do so. (I am a new person, sorry)

Any help on this?
I know when testing a variable like.. int x = 14, and if (a < 14) print something.. but instead of number I'd like to try with text.

Here is the source code:

```
int main()
 {
   char a = yes;
   char b = no;
   cout << "hi, press yes to start or no to cancel";
   cin >> a;

  if (a == yes)
   { 
  cout << "Cool person";
   }
  else if(b == no)
   {
  cout << "not a cool person";
  }
}
```

I keep getting "yes" is not defined in scope.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: There are plenty of good resources to learn C++ out there. Pick one and learn it. You won't get anywhere in C++ just by trying random things and hoping it works.

Comment: Does it really compile error free? `char a=yes`. `char` variable type should accept a single character like `Y`.

Comment: I learn from a youtube channel, and at school. But the truth is, I really don't have a lot of time as before, and google on the other hand just don't seem to have the right answer.

Comment: I got in codeblocks, error "yes" is not defined in scope

Comment: As suggested, it is considerably better for you to study from a book. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DUW4BMS/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_taft_p1_i1

Comment: I know these are really "noob questions" for many, but I'm trying to build a program that inquires testing a char instead of numbers, but it seems like errors are these are not found on google.

Comment: @macroland thanks, but I have ebooks provided already. I don't have time and the interest to read them, prefer videos.

Comment: Good recommendation, @macroland, I actually have that book and it's quite thorough.

Comment: @macroland would you suggest me to watch videos from a YouTube channel called "extern code" (formerly made by the new boston channel) as a starting point for learning c++ and learning the basic requirements of programming? Link: (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUQZ1qmKlLY) - I am currently learning c++ from this YouTuber's Videos, and from school but the teacher teaches too fast and I am unable to comprehend what she is saying at many times, and she is hardly in the office during her office hours. Thank You for your time and effort in reading my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a bare minimum, the following problems exist in your code:

- Tokens `yes` and `no` are identifiers. If you wanted them to be characters, that would be `'yes'` and `'no`. Except that they're *not* characters since they're too long. So, they should probably be strings like `"yes"` and `"no"`.
- The `b` variable is totally useless here, you should have *one* variable for receiving information from the user and checking it against multiple possible values. It's also a good idea to choose meaningful variable names.
- You aren't including the requisite headers, nor are you using the correct namespace for the `std` functions and types (either by explicitly prepending `std::` to each, or with a `using namespace std` for them all).

With that in mind, try out the following program as a starting point for your further education:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string userInput;

    std::cout << "Hi, enter yes to start or no to cancel: ";
    std::cin >> userInput; // probably better: std::getline(std::cin, userInput);

    if (userInput == "yes") {
        std::cout << "Cool person\n";
    } else if (userInput == "no") {
        std::cout << "Not a cool person\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Hey, can't you read? I said yes or no :-)\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that, used string class, still gives the same error.

Comment: @skyhigh: suggest you try again. That code compiles and runs just fine :-)

Comment: But thank you so much for your time in responding to my query. :)

Comment: Sir, I have one more question. The code works, Thank you. But i realize that you did not used the getline function when using string. Could you kindly tell when getline function is properly used? That is what my instructor told me when using a string function.

Comment: @skyhigh, you use `getline` when you want an entire line. Using `cin oper<<` with a string will only get you up to the first whitespace. In this case, it doesn't matter as you only want yes/no (with no spaces) but, if you're asking for someone's full name (for example), `getline` would be preferable.

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell you, instructed by my instructor, I am prone to use using namespace std; instead of std:: . I apologize for not including that on my source code.